# passing data immediately without using setstate

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to pass data when from alert dialogue box to the same screen immediately without using setstate?

```
 Widget setupShadeColorContainer(
      List<ShadeColorDatabase> allShadeData, BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300.0, // Change as per your requirement
      width: 300.0, // Change as per your requirement
      child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: allShadeData.length,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 4, crossAxisSpacing: 10, mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                rPassedChooseColor = allShadeData[i].rValue;
                gPassedChooseColor = allShadeData[i].gValue;
                bPassedChooseColor = allShadeData[i].bValue;
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.pop(context, [
                    rPassedChooseColor,
                    gPassedChooseColor,
                    bPassedChooseColor
                  ]);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(
                          allShadeData[i].rValue!.toInt(),
                          allShadeData[i].gValue!.toInt(),
                          allShadeData[i].bValue!.toInt(),
                          1),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, left: 5),
                      child: Text("${allShadeData[i].colorCode}"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  showAllColors(
      List<ShadeColorDatabase> shadeData, BuildContext context) async {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
            child: AlertDialog(
              title: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Fashion's Color",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: ChooseColor(0).appBarColor1, fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Form(
                        key: _form,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                ),
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: size.height * 0.001,
                                    horizontal: size.width * 0.030),
                                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.red, width: 1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                // labelText: 'Phone Number',
                                fillColor: const Color(0xffF6F9FA),
                                filled: true,
                                hintText: 'Search Color',
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: size.height * 0.012 +
                                        size.width * 0.012,
                                    color: Colors.black26),
                              ),
                              controller: searchController,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.035),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              content: setupShadeColorContainer(shadeData, context),
            ),
          );
        });
```

This is my dialogue box this dilogue box open over a screen and i want to pass data from this dilogue box to the same page immediately without using setstate is there any way i can achieve that?. Thanks

Comment: pass data possible, update ui not possible in general.(without any notifier)

Comment: yes i wanna pass data immediately without updating ui

Answer (score 0):

`showDialog()` can return future, and you can return data(myData) on closing dialog using

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop(myData);
```

```dart
    showAllColors() async {
    final data =   await showDialog(context: context, builder: (c){
     //  on closing dialog 
     Navigator.of(context).pop(passData);
     return data;
    }
```

When you use `showAllColors` try putting `await` on `async` method and also make sure to handle null data.